# RailsAdmin + Devise... Authenticating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I feel really silly right now... because this seems so fundamental.. But, how do I make rails_admin authenticate via devise, and the method `current_user.admin?`

I find it kind waste to create an entirely separate admin table for 1 admin. I just want a column on `User` that I simply check if it's true or not.

I have this:

```
config.current_user_method { current_user } # auto-generated

config.authorize_with do
  redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin?
end
```

Yes, I get the error: `No route matches {:controller=>"mixes", :action=>"index"} missing required keys: []`

If I make the `unless` argument something that returns true, such a `1==1` it works fine.

I'm also positive I have that controller/action/route. It's the homepage of my app which works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I needed `redirect_to main_app.root_path`. I googled what `main_app` is and now it makes sense.